# How ABP.io framework refreshes expired token?

Tags: abp, openiddict

I just started to work with ABP.io (v7.4.1). These steps are exactly what I did:

1. Create a new solution using `abp new MyProject -u blazor -csf --separate-auth-server`
2. Comment all dependencies (`DependsOn` attributes) to `AbpCachingStackExchangeRedisModule` and `AbpDistributedLockingModule`(in order to be able to run the project without Redis)
3. Change the default token lifetimes (to inspect what happens when a token expired):

   ```
   PreConfigure<OpenIddictServerBuilder>(builder =>
   {
       builder
           .SetAccessTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15))
           .SetIdentityTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
   });
   ```

**Then I ran the project and registered a user. While inspecting Network requests in Chrome Developer Tools, two question arose for me:**

1. While loggin in (either after a register or after a logout) two requests sent to Auth server for each `/connect/token` and `/connect/userinfo` endpoints. Why and is this really needed?
2. When I wait long enough for the token to expire; I expected an 401 error or redirecting to login page. But magically the user remains logged in (with thanks to a new request to `/connect/token` and `/connect/userinfo`). How ABP (or OpenIddict Module, I don't know exactly) handles this process(There isn't any refresh token neither in /token response nor in the `[OpenIddictTokens]` table)? Shouldn't I have codeed for refresh tokens?

And the last question: is there any explained tutorial/documentaion of how to customize OpenIddict module?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you are using abp, I would assume that you are using redis with it (since it comes by default). Redis is being used to store caches of the authentication server settings. Make sure that before your trial, you have flushed your redis server caches and try again, this my be the whole problem.

Answer (score 1):

> While loggin in (either after a register or after a logout) two requests sent to Auth server for each `/connect/token` and `/connect/userinfo` endpoints. Why and is this really needed?

The token and userinfo endpoints are called to respectively retrieve an access token after a successful authorization dance and get back the profile details of the logged in user.
It's part of the standard OpenID Connect authorization code flow defined here: https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#CodeFlowAuth.

Comment: Thanks @Kévin. I have no problem with sending A request to token and userinfo endpoints. But why TWO requests sent per EACH of token and userinfo endpoints?(2 reqs to token and 2 reqs for userinfo). Which line of provided documentation you've mentioned says two requests should sent to the token endpoint?

Comment: Ah, I had not realized it was for the same authentication dance. Can you reproduce the issue with only one tab opened (to exclude cases where two challenges would be started by two different tabs)? A network trace would definitely be helpful.